# assembly stack management through %esp

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I don't really understand why gcc has subtract 12 to esp before calling the function.

```
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp,%ebp
    sub $12,%esp

    socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    movl    $AF_INET,(%esp)
```

Comment: `sub` is subtraction not addition ;)  And it is to allocate local variables, doesn't have anything to do with the socket call.

Comment: Huh :-) edit. Am trying to get this.esp points to the stack, subtracting some value from it makes it point to an lower address, then the memory there between is used to for variables?Am I even making sense?

Comment: Yes, that's how it works.

Comment: Your code snippet is a mix of C and asm and doesn't make sense as written.

Comment: It is not written, its generated by gcc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current<sup>*</sup> x86 ABI requires the stack pointer to be aligned mod 16 at the time of function call. This is the typical reason for otherwise-unexplained adjustments of the stack pointer.

* I say *current* because GCC actually unilaterally changed the ABI and introduced this requirement somewhere back in the 3.x series. I don't have the references handy but maybe someone else can provide them. The change was intended to optimize for use of SIMD instructions, but isn't actually needed for that purpose, and ended up breaking ABI compatibility with old code when the old code calls back to new code that assumes alignment. The whole story is a big mess.

Comment: If the stack is aligned on a 16 byte boundary at the time of a call, then on a 32 bit X86, the call pushes the 4 byte return address onto the stack, and the stack is no longer on a 16 byte boundary. Also only the first parameter for the called function will be on a 16 byte boundary, the rest will depend on the size of the first parameter and alignment rules for the remaining parameters. I'm not sure what the point of this is.

Comment: @rcgldr: The point is that the callee can know the alignment of the stack pointer mod 16 upon entry, and thereby can create automatic-storage objects aligned to 16-byte boundaries, without having to align the stack pointer itself. Of course aligning the stack pointer itself would be trivial to do, and would only impose the cost on functions that need objects aligned to 16 bytes, and would have avoided breaking compatibility with the old ABI, which is why the whole convention is utterly stupid. But that's history...

Comment: Or the callee could just add one instruction to the typical entry sequence: | push ebp | mov ebp,esp | and esp,0fffffff0h | .

Comment: @rcgldr: Exactly. It's slightly more complicated if the callee is not using a frame pointer, but still not bad. You're repeating my exact arguments for why this change to the ABI by the GCC team was a mistake, but sadly it's a mistake that's in the distant past now and we're stuck with it.

Comment: Without a frame pointer the compiler could try to keep track of esp / rsp, but an _alloca() with a variable size would mess up that strategy. The compiler would have to save esp in some other register to handle the _alloca() case, so might as well use ebp. I assume visual studio doesn't do this.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you are pushing values of base pointer which decrements the values of stack pointer. Since push operation virtually take sp upwars essentially decrenting the address. Then the stack frame of c program consists of code seg above which there are arguments to function above which sits sp. Now when you want to access the 1st arg passed to function you need to add 12bytes since 3 words eventually 12 bytes  needs to be popped to get that argument.

http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/stack.html

I found this resource very helpful